# Custom '@' command?

Tags: slack, slack-api

In slack, is there a way for me to create a custom slack '@' command? E.g. `@here` or `@channel` notifies everyone in the channel. Can I create a custom group, such as `@coolPeople` that would, say, only notify John, Jack, Jill, and Jane, but not Adam and Amy? Thanks.

Comment: How is this a programming question? This is already a feature in Slack: https://slack.com/intl/en-gb/help/articles/212906697. Did you do any research?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It is called [user groups](https://slack.com/intl/en-de/help/articles/212906697) and works just as you describe.

You create a user group, e.g. named "coolpeople" and assign people to it. You can then use `@coolpeople` to notify them in a post. This also works form an app as described [here](https://api.slack.com/messaging/composing/formatting#mentioning-groups).

One caveat: This is a premium feature and therefore not available to Slack workspaces on the free tier.